# Is there any way to redo a git undo operation on uncommited files

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I am using git source control in visual studio 2013. From my uncommitted changes, I selected undo option in visual studio team explorer on the csproj file (I just wanted to remove the added files), but it has undone all my edited uncommitted files in the project. Is there any way to redo this operation? Or any other suggestion to recover my edits?

Answer (score 0):

Giving you one suggestion that if you are working with git then use the command line tool(http://git-scm.com). It is the most powerful and widely used tool.Atleast give it a try, i am sure you will use it forever.

```
git reset <file>
```

Remove the specified file from the staging area, but leave the working directory unchanged. This unstages a file without overwriting any changes.

```
git reset
```

Reset the staging area to match the most recent commit, but leave the working directory unchanged. This unstages all files without overwriting any changes, giving you the opportunity to re-build the staged snapshot from scratch.

```
git reset --hard
```

Reset the staging area and the working directory to match the most recent commit. In addition to unstaging changes, the --hard flag tells Git to overwrite all changes in the working directory, too. Put another way: this obliterates all uncommitted changes, so make sure you really want to throw away your local developments before using it.